# Adding a Search bar to the Filters Section for a Specific Object type in Django Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to add search functionality to filter the the object types in the filters section (right-side) of django admin panel something as shown below

[image: My Question shown as a picture with a search bar in the filters section]

I'm not sure if there is any default way of doing this or plugin for this

Thanks in advance if any expansion is required that can be provided